# Error from Holographic Remoting for Play Mode: Failed to enable remoting runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I’m trying to visualize my game object movement on the Hololens 2 in real-time while it runs in the Unity editor (receiving transform data from ros-sharp topic).
But after following Microsoft documentation and making sure of the correct configuration, I set the correct IP adress (connecting through USB cable), but unfortunately I couldn’t see anything on the Holographic Remoting Player and I get "Failed to enable remoting runtime" error on Unity console.
I tried it on a second machine and I received another error "Play to Holographic Remoting is disconnected unexpectedly, Disconnect Reason = VideoFormatNotAvailableAvailable".
Plus I can't find the "Emulation Mode" in Mixed Reality -> Remoting, I only have the Holographic Remoting for Play Mode.
I’m using Holographic Remoting Player v2.8.1.0, Unity 2020.3.31f1, UWP 10.10240.0, Visual Studio 2022 and the latest version of packages and plugins.
First machine Graphics NVIDIA GeForce820M
Second machine Gaphics card NVIDIA Quadro P1000.
How can I solve this issue and is there another method to deploy my app on Hololens 2 and receive real-time position data from Unity other than using the Holographic Remoting Player ?

Drive link for screenshots: https://photos.app.goo.gl/kvQ8sV5kkLgmy8qX8

Thank you in advance for helping me out, I really appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

VideoFormatNotAvailable error indicates a video decoding issue, and you may check hardware video decoding functionality on your development devices. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/remote-rendering/resources/troubleshoot#error-disconnected-videoformatnotavailable

You may also consider disabling the NVIDIA graphics card driver for troubleshooting in Windows Device Manager if you have integrated GPU.

-> **I set the correct IP address (connecting through USB cable)**

Please make sure you are using the IP address from USB connection. The one displaying on Holographic Remoting Player app prefers IP from WIFI connection than USB connection. You may turn off WIFI temporarily for testing.

-> **I can't find the "Emulation Mode" in Mixed Reality -> Remoting, I only have the Holographic Remoting for Play Mode**

Emulation Mode is used with Windows XR Plugin, it’s recommended to use OpenXR Plugin, which should be your current in-use plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In fact I disabled my NVIDIA graphic card and now I'm having the same error on both laptops ""Failed to enable remoting runtime". I set the IP adress from USB connection as you mentioned, and tried it with IP displayed on the app over WiFi but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried to run Unity Hub as an administrator? Please refer to the discussion on https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-HolographicRemoting-Samples/issues/58.

Comment: Yes I did, I tried to run Unity Hub as an administrator and tried also to run Unity without elevation like suggested by yl-msft comment but none of these solutions worked unfortunately.

Comment: I don't see 820M listed as capable H.264 encode graphic card https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new . This is a requirement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/holographic-remoting-system-requirements#remote-pc P1000 is though.